# Back up multiple hard drives to a folder on Google Drive?

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, backup, google-drive

I have a computer with three hard drives that I want to back up to my google drive account. I want a separate folder for each of the drives, all within a single "Backups" folder. I have been looking at a lot of different options for getting this done, but I don't think I've found one that works best. What is a good way to go about this?

Comment: You want the whole disk? Or do you want files useable? And if so also the system files?  If yes on the 1st: I would suggest to make an ISO of each disk using `dd`.  If yes on the 2nd I would start looking at `rsynch` and set up incremental backups (ie. a backup that only uploads changed files). But that would defeat the "single Backups" part ;-)

Comment: Not time for a full answer, I would use a sync tool such as insync,  mount the drives and symlink to a Backups folder within your google drive folder, your sync tool will take care of uploading to google drive.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to backup to Google Drive... mainly because your upload speed is probably so low, that it'll take **forever** to complete. Also, trying to restore your disk image/files would be very difficult, as your image/files would not be local, but rather, in the cloud. Get yourself a very large external USB 3.0 hard disk and image backup to that.

Answer (score 0):

> Gnome Disk Utility

It is native to Ubuntu and can be used to create a whole disk backup. It is rather user friendly. It takes 2 clicks to create a whole disk backup. Top right the 3 lines:

[image]

and ...

[image]

- an alternative would be clonezilla.

---

You can also do this from command line:

> dd

Warning: `dd` can and will happily destroy the location that is used as the output file. Without any warning. So before you do this make sure you have a emergency backup made. Example:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/backup_sda.iso
```

would pick the whole of sda and put it in the outputfile. Add a digit to sda (`sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/tmp/backup_sda1.iso`) if you want just a partition. And you can then upload it to google drive.

> tar

```
cd /
sudo tar -cpzf backup_sda1.tar.gz --exclude=/backup_sda1.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

would make 1 compressed file of all your files. And, again, upload it to google drive.

Comment: Consider how long it would take to upload a disk image file to Google Drive... **forever**. And how would one restore it to bare metal? Rather a large external USB 3.0 disk drive with local backup/restore would be better.

Comment: I agree but it was the main part of the question ;=)

Comment: I've got no problem telling the OP that they've got a bad idea :-)) And I did :-)